# TOC chapter entry alignment

Tags: table-of-contents

I am having trouble formatting the TOC for a document. I have long chapter titles which wrap onto two lines of TOC text. The problem is that the second line of a single chapter title is aligned with the chapter number, but I need it to align with the beginning of the title text on the first line:

[image: Bad alignment with long chapter titles]

I am using a style file that floats around my school, and here is the \l@chapter definition:

```
\def\l@chapter#1#2{%
\pagebreak[3]
\vskip .75em plus 1pt \@tempdima 1.5em 
\begingroup
    \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
    \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
    \leavevmode {\MakeUppercase{#1}\mydotfill \hbox to\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}}
    \par
\endgroup
}
```

Any ideas for how to get the second line to align with the text on the first??

thanks!

Comment: Also, when adding a chapter, the title is added to the TOC with this:
     \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}                                                     {\protect\numberline{\thechapter} \normalsize\MakeUppercase{#1}}%

Comment: Do you know that you can use a different title for TOC? Just make use of `\chapter[short]{long}`.

Comment: I don't have that problem with my thesis class (which also had to have the all-caps chapter titles in the ToC). What's your base document class, so I can see if my method works on yours?

Comment: You could take a look at  the  `titletoc` package. It is automaticaly the case that multiline titles have all their lines aligned with the first one.

Answer (score 3):

Here is perhaps an easier way of achieving it:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\makeatletter
\def\l@chapter#1#2{%
\pagebreak[3]
\vskip .75em plus 1pt \@tempdima 1.5em 
\begingroup
  \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
  \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
  \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
  \hskip -\leftskip
  \leavevmode \MakeUppercase{#1}\dotfill \hbox to\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}
  \par
\endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{This is a super long chapter heading that requires more than one line in the Table of Contents}

\end{document}
```

The adjustment of `\leftskip` is taken directly from the definition of `\l@chapter` in [`book.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/book.cls).

Answer (score 0):

My wife came up with a solution! (similar to Sigur). I put a manual line break and \hspace* in the short title, and adjusted the hspace distance until it lined up. Not elegant, but effective!